# How to change this error message into alert pop up in php?

Tags: php

I want to modify this code into pop up alert. Currently, this code only produce error message. I want to modify it so when course clashed, the pop up will appear

```
 if($clash_courses==1)
{
    $error_msg .= 'Course ';
    $c = 0;
    foreach($course_id as $id){
        $c++;
        $error_msg .= $id;
        if($c<count($course_id))
        $error_msg .= ' and ';
    }

    $error_msg .= ' have clashed.';

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by popup? Like a Javascript `alert` or a popup webpage? Either way, you'll need Javascript for it and you'll need to show us how you're outputting the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if($clash_courses==1)
{
    echo '<script type = "text/javascript">';
    $error_msg .= 'Course ';
    $c = 0;
    foreach($course_id as $id){
        $c++;
        $error_msg .= $id;
        if($c<count($course_id))
        $error_msg .= ' and ';
    }

    $error_msg .= ' have clashed.';
    echo('alert("' . htmlspecialchars(str_replace('"', '\\"', $error_msg)) . '");</script>');

}
```

Not the cleanest solution, but it should work.  Another solution would be to access this script via AJAX, which can then feed the error back to the client-side as an 'error object' or even just a simple message that the client can then `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP is on the server side.

Anything you want as a "popup" on the client side (the browser), you need some javascript or css magic.

Comment: @DaveRandom how else am I to answer?

Comment: Maybe with a code sample? I have purposefully not posted an answer until the OP can explain more about what he wants to do and what he has at the moment. I mean, obviously you're not wrong, and this isn't worthy of a downvote, but reflex "you can't do it" answers are neither useful nor productive. IMHO.

Comment: @DaveRandom I am **not** giving a code solution to something of which I have no idea of the background. Telling the OP to research javascript and/or css solutions is the only way I see fit. _IMHO_

Comment: Fair enough - but do it in a comment not an answer, and don't shout. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/. I'm not having a go by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In a raw way :

```
$error_msg .= ' have clashed.';
$popup="<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('"$.error_msg."');
</script>";
```

if you "echo" `$popup` in some html, it will show a pop-up alert.

Comment: shouldnt `alert('"$.error_msg."');` be `alert('".$error_msg."');` the `.` in wrong place..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to popup your message you can do it  by `Javascript alertbox` but if you want it to look attractive then you can use [Twitter Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)
which also show you the demo

Comment: great!! but can it be used in php ? sorry, im newbie in this area

Comment: yes @user1551791 i used in my project.You can use in your project also it looks good.